# How to trigger bootstrap modal on child component ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I use bootstrap and angular. Imagine a situation where I have a situation with a parent and a child.

Table component is parent
Modal component is child.

in Table component i want to click on edit button and open Modal ( child component )
In modal component i want to show bootstrap modal

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is problem because button trigger is on parent component....
How to open modal from parent data and show?

This is parent table component.

```
<tr *ngFor="let menu of allMenus | searchInput:searchTerm; let i=index"> 
    <td> 
        <button (click)="toggleModal(menu)" class="btn btn-secondary mr-3"> Edit </button>
        <button (click)="removeMenu(menu)" class="btn btn-secondary"> Remove </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your child component tag (selector) with a ng-container with a *ngIf checking a boolean value (displayChild), try this:

```js
public displayChild: boolean = false;

onToggle(){
  displayChild == false ? true : false; 
}
```

```html
<button (click)="onToggle()">Click!</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="displayChild">
  <child-component></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: and the problem is not that the component appears then modal which have a trigger .....

Comment: you says that trigger button is in parents component, and modal is in child component, but in your code you have the modal component in the same template, just under the button